# You need to install an app for this task- windows phone error (ionic)

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

I am developing an hybrid app for android and wp8 using ionic. It works fine on android platform but when i recently use this on wp8, it is showing me "**"You need to install an app for this task do you want to search it on store?**." when i click on some links (internal app links). Please can anybody tell me why this is happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the ms-appx that is being added by ms causes the problem.

To solve this issue, we need to notify AngularJS that links with an ms-appx prefix are a-okay by us. Luckily AngularJS supports this functionality. But how it supports it varies across AngularJS versions.

**AngularJS 1.2+: $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist**

**AngularJS <1.2: $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist**

The best place to put this code is inside your **app.js** file. The code I'm using on Windows Phone is as follows:

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);
```